# Does the order of columns in a non-clustered ColumnStore index matter?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, columnstore

I'm reading about creating a non-clustered ColumnStore index. I noticed that when I modify an already created non-clustered ColumnStore in SQL Server Management Studio I have an option to change the order of the columns. Does the order of the columns matter?

Comment: Still hold true for 2012 and 2014 - [Does not physically store columns in a sorted order. Instead, it stores data to improve compression and performance. Pre-sorting the data before creating the columnstore index is not required, but can improve columnstore compression.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx)

Comment: This question is about a non-clustered index vs the suggested question which is about a clustered index. Also, the issue about SSMS isn't addressed in the suggested question.

Comment: @ytoledano same for clustered and non-clustered, also the issue about SSMS doesn't need to be addressed. You can change the order when using DDL as well.